# Does Team Foundation Server have a REST API?

Tags: bug-trackers, visual-studio-team-services

I could have sworn that I stumbled upon documentation for Microsoft Team Foundation Server (TFS) REST API at some point, but can't seem to find it now.  I can only seem to find stuff on their .NET SDK.

Does Team Foundation Server have a REST API for reading, creating, and editing work items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found it!

It's called [Team System Web Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892990%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) and it lets you [create new work items via a URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822136%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

I found a few links regarding the TFS API

[Extending Team Foundation Server from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146.aspx)

> Team Foundation is a multitiered application for which users install some components on >client computers and other components on the application tier. You can extend Team 
>   Foundation by using its client object model on the client computers or the server object >model on the application tier.

[TFS API Wrapper from CodePlex](http://tfsapiwrapper.codeplex.com/)

> A simple wrapper that encapsulates exposed functions of the Microsoft Team Foundation >Server (TFS) client API

Answer (score 3):

Team Foundation Server does offer a REST API ([as of May 2014](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/bharry/a-new-api-for-visual-studio-online)), in both Visual Studio Online and subsequent versions of on-premises Team Foundation Server.

Documentation is available [here](http://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/reference/reference-vso-overview-vsi).

Comment: The API seems to be for Visual Studio Online only and "in a future release [for] Team Foundation Server". In the comments the author says: "Yes, it will be available in on premises TFS in a future release.  I don't have an estimate for when yet." Their website doesn't mention any support for TFS.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of work, it's finally available! 
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/overview

Comment: Can you include some of the details within the body of the answer, please?